# Configure logging level in .net console application

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I'm writing a .net console application, and I've a problem to set logging levels. I've created appsettings files with "Logging" section, but it doesn't work -  I set the level to Error and still gets Info level errors.
I know that appsettings are loading correctly because the rest of the settings are correctly binded.

My main class:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true);
            config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true);
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            if (args != null)
                config.AddCommandLine(args);
        })
        .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
            services.AddMagic())
        .RunConsoleAsync();
}
```

and my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Postgres": {
    "Host": "localhost",
    "DatabaseName": "db",
    "Username": "admin",
    "Password": "admin",
    "MinLogLevel": "Error"
  },
  "Redis": {
    "Host": "localhost:6379",
    "Password": null
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the rest of your appsettings file look like? Just to verify that the Logging section is in a proper place.

Comment: I've just add whole appsettings file to question instead of only logging section.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding a direct login configuration resolved my problem:

```
.ConfigureLogging((context, config) =>                    
    config.AddConfiguration(context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging")))
```

Whole main function:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true);
            config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true);
            if (args != null)
                config.AddCommandLine(args);
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((context, config) =>
            config.AddConfiguration(context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging")))
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
            services.AddMagic())
        .RunConsoleAsync();
}
```