# How to create a Logger in .NET 6 Program.cs

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I have a Data.Migrations project, which will run any Entity Framework Migrations to update the database model.
Recently I have updated this project to .NET 6 and added a logger to the `Program.cs` using the following code:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
_logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
```

This results however in `_logger == null`.

How can I add a logger to the Program.cs?

Comment: How / Where are you adding `ILogger` to the service collection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure logging level in .net console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68446152/configure-logging-level-in-net-console-application)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing this line:

```
serviceCollection.AddLogging();
```

So the full code would look like this:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddLogging();
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
_logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
```

Answer (score 11):

If you're using a minimal hosting model, it`s pretty simple:

```
...
var app = builder.Build();
app.Logger.LogInformation("Starting Application");
...
```

The preceding code is show in the official [ASP.NET Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/#log-in-programcs)

Comment: What if the logger reference is needed before the call to `builder.Build();`?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the above answer by @Olegi, the logger for Program.cs can be created. However if this logger has to log in the logging providers configured on the WebApplicationBuilder, below line can be used

```
var logger = builder.Logging.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
```

Comment: The compiler generates a warning for this code: "Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'"

Comment: You could try using builder.Services.PostConfigure or Configure. I haven't tried myself.

Answer (score 1):

Are you not considering [SeriLog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog)? I found it quite useful for my work. It comes with good support for structured logging and log level filtering. The [UseSerilog](https://andrewlock.net/adding-serilog-to-the-asp-net-core-generic-host/) extension comes handy. More on Logging [here](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-8-improving-logging-performance-with-source-generators/).

A word of advice. [Don't use BuildServiceProvider](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-7-analyzers-for-minimal-apis/). It is a potential code smell.

Added some reference links from the author of "ASP .Net core in action" book.

Disclaimer: I am not associated with [Andrew Lock](https://andrewlock.net/) by any means though I would love to. The man does write good articles on .Net.

Comment: Serilog is something worth considering when logging, but does any of this explain how to log in Program.cs? With or without Serilog?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. Serilog static logger does help to log from Program.cs. I use the same.

Comment: Can you get an environment-specific Serilog logger in `Main()`?