# Program cs how to call interface net 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I try to call interface in program class. When i do that i create variable and assign interface to the variable for example `var logger = ILogger` but i got error ILogger is a type, which is not valid in the given context. Last time that i use it in .net 3 i was writing the code in startup class not in program class. First i will create `private readonly ILogger _log` and than in the consturctor i will assign it `public Startup(ILogger log){_log=log;}` and after that i was able to access it _log. How could do the same in .net 6 inside program class.

Comment: You need an instance of a class that implements ilogger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Logger in .NET 6 Program.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71562958/how-to-create-a-logger-in-net-6-program-cs)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that works for me.The code is below :
`var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection(); serviceCollection.AddAlkaloidLogging(); var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider(); var _logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ReportingApp.Core.Logging.ILogger>();`
Thank you [@Macro] you link was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this, I will mention two ways the first would be like this:

```
var logger = LoggerFactory.Create(config =>
{
    config.AddConsole();
}).CreateLogger("Program");
```

```
app.MapGet("/Test", async context =>
{
    logger.LogInformation("Testing logging in Program.cs");
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Testing");
});
```

the second one would be very simple, just put this line that already works:

```
app.Logger.LogInformation("Testing logging in Program.cs");
```

I really hope I helped!